# Android Photo/Media/File Runtime permission problem

Tags: java, android, runtime-permissions

I need Photo, Media & File permission to keep my app data in CSV format in my local phone storage.

```
 public void permissionTake() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Activity_login.this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

      
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Activity_login.this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
       
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Activity_login.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
    } else {
    }
}
```

> Those line of codes works fine in a previous project with min android
> version 16 and targeted version 27. But in a new project it only ask
> for 'photos and media' permission. Not 'Files'. For that the CSV file
> is failed to stored in my storage.

[image: This is my old project's screenshot]

[image: This is my new project screenshot. FILES is missing here.]

Comment: Which version has new project?

Comment: minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29

Comment: There are no problem with photo and media. But Files.

Comment: So only a different project running on the same device? What kind of device? Which version has device?

Comment: `need Photo, Media & File permission ` I have never realized/known/seen that there were separate permissions as all what you can ask for is WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Strange story.

Comment: Yes on the same device. Android 10.

Comment: Look at my screenshot. I am trying to solve this problem since yesterday.

Comment: On Android 10 you cannot write to getExternalStorageDirectory anymore. Except if you requested legacyExternalStorage (or something like that) in manifest file. Please compare the projects.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it & let you know. :)

Comment: But my previous project works fine in same device !

Comment: Reread my comment: Compare the manifest files!

Comment: targeted version 27 solved my problem. But 29 not.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.